# jquery different values in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

i would like to set two different values for width and height according of window width, and put them into function. I try to write:

```
...
width: +cdwidth+, 
height: +cdheight+,
...
```

unfortunately this is not working. Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
<script type="textjavascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

            var widthWindow = $(window).width(); 

            if (widthWindow > 600) {

                var cdwidth = 500;
                var cdheight = 100;

            }else{

                var cdwidth = 300;
                var cdheight = 60;
            };

    });

    var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({
        year : 2016,
        month : 3,
        day : 21,
        hour : 0,
        ampm : "am",
        minute : 0,
        second : 0,
        width: cdwidth, 
        height: cdheight,  
        rangeHi:"day",
        style:"flip"    // <- no comma on last item!
    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: try putting that `new Countdown` call inside the `$(document).ready`. or make the `cdwidth` and `cdheight` variables global

Comment: Please let me know if my answer did not work for you  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36030962/4763793

Answer (score 0):

Declare  `var cdwidth` and  `var cdheight`  as global variable.

```
var cdwidth,cdheight;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var widthWindow = $(window).width(); 
    if (widthWindow > 600) {
        cdwidth = 500;
         cdheight = 100;
    }else{
         cdwidth = 300;
         cdheight = 60;
     }
});
```

**Demo for showing global scope**

```js
 var cdwidth;
 var cdheight;

 $(document).ready(function() {
   cdwidth = 300;
   cdheight = 60;
   test();
 });

 function test() {
   alert(cdwidth);
   alert(cdheight);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this:

```
<script type="textjavascript">
var cdwidth,
    cdheight,
    myCountdown1;
    $(document).ready(function() {

            var widthWindow = $(window).width(); 

            if (widthWindow > 600) {

                cdwidth = 500;
                cdheight = 100;

            }else{

                cdwidth = 300;
                cdheight = 60;
            };

    myCountdown1 = new Countdown({
        year : 2016,
        month : 3,
        day : 21,
        hour : 0,
        ampm : "am",
        minute : 0,
        second : 0,
        width: cdwidth, 
        height: cdheight,  
        rangeHi:"day",
        style:"flip"    // <- no comma on last item!
    }); 
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Well the biggest problem is that i can`t put that new Countdown call inside the $(document).ready. This script is pretty sick

Comment: Ok guys, i got it!

'
<script type="text/javascript">
 var cdwidth;
 var cdheight;
 var widthWindow = $(window).width(); 
 
 if (widthWindow > 600) {  
  cdwidth = 500;
  cdheight = 100;
 }else{
  cdwidth = 300;
  cdheight = 60;
 };

 resize(cdwidth,cdheight);
 function resize(w,h){
  var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({
   year : 2016,
   month : 3,
   day : 21,
   hour : 0,
   ampm : "am",
   minute : 0,
   second : 0,
   width: w, 
   height: h,  
   rangeHi:"day",
   style:"flip" 
  }); 
 };
</script>
'